# Jenkins-Plot plugin : Send plot generated graph in Email

Tags: jenkins, plot, plugins

I have installed Plot graph plugin in jenkins. Its generating a Plot based on last 5 builds(Configured to last 5 builds). Also, I am using email - extension plugin to send email once build is completed.

My requirement is to send the Plot graph in this email.

Can you please help me out here.

Regards,
Chandan